# Pra que serve o arquivo .component.spec no angular2

Tags: angular

Estou utilizando o angular cli em meu projeto, e ao gerar um component, ele cria automaticamente um arquivo .component.spec.ts

Alguém sabe me dizer pra que serve este arquivo .spec?
Preciso realmente dele ou posso excluir?

Comment: Deve ser alguma coisa relacionada a especificações  ou configuração do `TypeScript`.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters até onde sei, as configurações do TypeScript (quando usado), ficam em um arquivo chamado `typings`. A não ser que tenham alterado algo nesses últimos updates.

Answer (score 4):

Os arquivos de `spec` são testes de unidade para os arquivos de origem. 
A convenção para aplicações Angular 2 é ter um arquivo `.spec.ts` para cada arquivo `.ts`.

Documentação: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html

Comment: O que há de errado com a resposta?

Answer (score 2):

De fato os arquivos .spec.ts são uma forma de realizar teste unitários no Angular 2 com a estrutura de teste do Jasmine, você pode executar os testes com o comando via CLI "ng test".